# Above amounts in python

Tags: python, if-statement, thonny

Once again I am having trouble with THONNY python. What I am having trouble with this time is that you need at ***LEAST*** 40$ to buy this. But what I am doing is you have to have 40$ ***exactly***. How can I change it so the player has ***at least*** 40$?
This is what **I** have put:(This bit below doesnt matter***)

```
elif balance_a == "40" and select == "g":
```

What do I change?

[*** = the select == "g" part doesn't matter.]
[If I am unclear please say.]

***EDIT: IT WORKED THANK U! HAve a good day/night!***

Comment: did you try balance_a >= "40"

Comment: Why are you using string for balance? It is true in Python that `"41"  >= "40"` will give `True`, however `"40" + "40"` will give `"4040"`.

Comment: What is the type of  `balance_a`? Can you provide an example of its value?

Answer (score 0):

As far as what I understood, you want 40 or more, if this is the case do

```
 elif balance_a >= 40 and select == "g":
```

This makes it greater than or equal to, which is the same as at least

Comment: You can't compare mixed types in python 3.0, and in 2.0 it gives non-intuitive results. Therefore I believe you need `balance_a >= 40`

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood your issue, this is the solution:

```py
elif balance_a >= 40 and select == "g":`?
```

You have to use `>=` rather than `=`.

I assume that `balance_a` is a numeric type, otherwise you have to convert it:

```py
elif float(balance_a) >= 40 and select == "g":`?
```

Comment: Oh, I didnt see the float part of your  awnser, lemme try that xD

Comment: This is what happens when I put float in front:     elif float(balance_a) >= "40" and select == "g":
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Look at my code: you have to remove `"` around 40